# How to combine date and time using dayjs?

Tags: javascript, dayjs

If following data represent date and time respectively:

```
date: 2023-04-04
time: 13:02:00.963+00:00
```

How do I combine above date and time using dayjs, so it looks as below format:

```
2023-04-04T13:02:00.963Z
```

Is there any built-in method to do this? and what're the alternatives?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the inbuilt [`Date.toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) for this in case you are wondering

```js
const date = '2023-04-04'
const time = '13:02:00.963+00:00'

const datetime = new Date(`${date}T${time}`).toISOString()

console.log(datetime)
```

or using [dayjs](https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/as-iso-string#docsNav)

```js
const date = '2023-04-04'
const time = '13:02:00.963+00:00'

const datetime = dayjs(`${date}T${time}`).toISOString()

console.log(datetime)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.7/dayjs.min.js"></script>
```

or using [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/)

```js
const date = '2023-04-04'
const time = '13:02:00.963+00:00'

const datetime = moment(`${date}T${time}`).toISOString()

console.log(datetime)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

or using luxon

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime

const date = '2023-04-04'
const time = '13:02:00.963+00:00'

const datetime = DateTime.fromISO(`${date}T${time}`, { setZone: true }).toISO()
console.log(datetime)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/3.3.0/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const date = dayjs("2023-04-04");
const time = dayjs("13:02:00", "HH:mm:ss");
const dateTime = date.hour(time.hour()).minute(time.minute()).second(time.second());
```

Answer (score 0):

To combine a date and time using Day.js, you can use the .set() method to set the time part of the date to the desired time value. Here is an example:

```
const dayjs = require('dayjs');

// create a date object with a specific date
const date = dayjs('2023-04-23');

// create a time object with a specific time
const time = dayjs('10:30:00', 'HH:mm:ss');

// combine the date and time objects
const dateTime = date.set('hour', time.hour()).set('minute', time.minute()).set('second', time.second());

console.log(dateTime.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')); // Output: 2023-04-23 10:30:00
```